# Fused Location Provider should invoke onLocationChanged() only when user's location changes

Tags: android, location

My app requires user's location only when user location changes. I can very easily know the user location when wifi/gps are turned on and when I code this:

```
mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);    //10 seconds                    
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

By coding this, the onLocationChanged() is called after every 10 seconds even if user's location is not changed. Why?
This is unneccessarily draining the battery. I want that when user moves then only my app should have the updated location.
In Google I/O 2013, it is said that through sensors (Fused Location Provider) user's location need not be traced if he is sitting at one place.
I commented the above lines and coded:

```
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50.0f);    //50 meters
```

I can see only once that I walked 50 meters and the onLocationChanged() is called. I have never seen onLocationChanged() invoked at other times.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get handles to the UI view objects

    // Create a new global location parameters object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    /**
     * If below two lines are commented the location change method is not called.
     */
   // mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);                      //Set the update interval
    //mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);         // Set the interval ceiling to one minute

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50.0f);


    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();

}
}

  public void getLocation(View v) {

    // If Google Play Services is available
    if (servicesConnected()) {

        // Get the current location
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        // Display the current location in the UI
        mLatLng.append("\nLast Location: "+LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, currentLocation));
    }
}

public void startUpdates(View v) {
    mUpdatesRequested = true;

    if (servicesConnected()) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.connected);

    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}
```

@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.connected);

```
    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }
}
```

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

```
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);

    // In the UI, set the latitude and longitude to the value received
    mLatLng.append("\nLoc Changed:"+LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, location));
}

/**
 * In response to a request to start updates, send a request
 * to Location Services
 */
private void startPeriodicUpdates() {

    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_requested);
}
```

How can I have the onLocationChanged() invoke only when the user's location change. If the user is sitting at one place, this method should not be invoked.